# Dropdown Values not change in Flutter Modal

Tags: android, flutter, widget, dropdown, setstate

I have this `Dropdown` Widget in a `Modal` and I cannot Change the Value in the Widget while I'm using `setState` and everytime I change the value, I should close the Modal and then the Value is Changed.

this is my Code:

```dart
var chosenRecentDay = 1;
List<int> daysList = [for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++) i];
int defaultDropDownValue = 1;

showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 500.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 150.0,
                height: 45.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    value: defaultDropDownValue,
                    menuMaxHeight: 250.0,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle_rounded,
                      color: Color(0xffF85E63),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
                    items: daysList
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>((dynamic value) {
                      var convertedList = value.toString();
                      return DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                              child: Text(
                                convertedList,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xffF85E63),
                                  fontFamily: 'Lalezar',
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        defaultDropDownValue = val!;
                        chosenRecentDay = val;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a modal and the outer `setState` doesn't affect the modal after it's created. (It doesn't trigger a rebuild of a modal.)

One solution is to wrap your widget with a `StatefulBuilder` like this:

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        // return your widgets here
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Remember, if you need to update the state of both the parent widget and the modal, you can use different names for the `StateSetter` of the `StatefulBuilder` and the `setState` of the parent widget.